# How to handle validation errors and exceptions in a RESTful Spring MVC controller?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

For example, how to handle validation errors and possible exceptions in this controller action method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST)
@ResponseBody
public FooDto create(@Valid FooDTO fooDto, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return null; // what to do here?
                     // how to let the client know something has gone wrong?
    } else {
        fooDao.insertFoo(fooDto); // What to do if an exception gets thrown here?
                                  // What to send back to the client?
        return fooDto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Send back an appropriate error response and/or code. I don't understand the question, I guess.

Comment: The action returns a `FooDTO`, how to send back an appropriate response with some validation error messages?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Throw an exception if you have an error, and then use [`@ExceptionHandler` to annotate another method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler) which will then handle the exception and render the appropriate response.

Comment: He could even use `throw new BindException(bindingResult)` and then have handler for BindException.

Comment: He shouldn't even have to explicitly throw a `BindException`.  Just remove the `BindingResult` argument from the method and spring will throw a `BindException` if there are any validation errors.  And the exception handler method can access all the error details because `BindException` implements `BindingResult` and `Errors`.

Answer (score 6):

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST)
@ResponseBody
public FooDto create(@Valid FooDTO fooDto) {
//Do my business logic here
    return fooDto;

}
```

Create a n exception handler:

```
@ExceptionHandler( MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(value = org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
protected CustomExceptionResponse handleDMSRESTException(MethodArgumentNotValidException objException)
{

    return formatException(objException);
}
```

I don't know if this is the correct approach i am following. I would appreciate if you could tell me what you have done for this issue.

Comment: This will not work since there is already handler method for MethodArgumentNotValidException defined in ResponseEntityExceptionHandler, check this asnwer for further details, https://stackoverflow.com/a/38282563/4184240