# How do you retain Spring's Built-In REST Response JSON body with a @ControllerAdvise (and @RestControllerAdvise) Class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In Spring 4.x, if you use a `@RestControllerAdvise` (or `@ControllerAdvice`) that extends `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`, the default exception handling with nice and informative JSON response bodies, is no longer returned by default for arguments marked as `@Valid`.

How do you get the default JSON bodies to be returned while using a `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` based `@RestControllerAdvice`?

The following is a simple, yet full example describing this question. Using these classes:

```
@RestController
class CarsController {

  @PostMapping("/cars")
  public void createCar(@RequestBody @Valid Car car) {
    System.out.println("Creating " + car);
    throw new WhateverException();
  }

  @ExceptionHandler(WhateverException.class)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED)
  public void handleWhateverException(){
    System.out.println("Handling a WhateverException.");
  }

}

class Car {

  @NotNull
  private String make;

  @NotNull
  private String model;

  ...getter/setters omitted for brevity...
}

class WhateverException extends RuntimeException {}
```

If you submit a `POST` to `/cars` with

```
{
    "make": "BMW"
}
```

It responds with a `400` and the following body:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1491020374642,
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException",
  "errors": [
    {
      "codes": [
        "NotNull.car.model",
        "NotNull.model",
        "NotNull.java.lang.String",
        "NotNull"
      ],
      "arguments": [
        {
          "codes": [
            "car.model",
            "model"
          ],
          "arguments": null,
          "defaultMessage": "model",
          "code": "model"
        }
      ],
      "defaultMessage": "may not be null",
      "objectName": "car",
      "field": "model",
      "rejectedValue": null,
      "bindingFailure": false,
      "code": "NotNull"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Validation failed for object='car'. Error count: 1",
  "path": "/cars"
}
```

However if you move the exception handling method to it's own class marked `@RestControllerAdvice`, which extends from `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` such as the following:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(WhateverException.class)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED)
  public void handleWhateverException(WhateverException e, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    System.out.println("Handling a WhateverException.");
  }

}
```

You'll get a `400` with an **empty body**, which is caused by `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` providing a method (`handleMethodArgumentNotValid(..)`), which builds a response where the body is `null`.

How would you alter this `@RestControllerAdvice` class to trigger the original handling that occurs, which provides a JSON body describing why the submitted request is invalid?

Comment: Is this how your `RestExceptionHandler` looks like in reality? Did you truncated the real version for demo purposes?

Comment: I of course can't post my companies code, so this is simply a contrived example to illustrate the question only.

Comment: Got the same problem. If you already solved it or found a different solution it can be helpful for me :)

Comment: No, I have not solved this. I had to abandon Spring's built-in handling because of this situation. It'd be great if someone did solve this as I'd love to go back to using it.

Answer (score 5):

You can **emulate** spring's behaviour overriding in your `@ControllerAdvice` extending `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`:

```
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleExceptionInternal(Exception ex, Object body,
                             HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    if (body == null) {
        body = ImmutableMap.builder()
                   .put("timestamp", LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toEpochSecond())
                   .put("status", status.value())
                   .put("error", status.getReasonPhrase())
                   .put("message", ex.getMessage())
                   .put("exception", ex.getClass().getSimpleName())  // can show FQCN like spring with getName()
                   .put("path", ((ServletWebRequest)request).getRequest().getRequestURI())
                   .build();
    }
    return super.handleExceptionInternal(ex, body, headers, status, request);
}
```

* `ImmutableMap` needs guava.

**`LocalDateTime` needs java8.

Comment: The best idea I've seen so far. Thx !

Comment: Where did this code come from? Is there a way to see the original Spring implementation that builds the body to ensure this code is up-to-date? Or, even more preferably, just call the default spring handler directly from my override of it?

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
   @RestControllerAdvice
    class RestExceptionHandler {

      @ExceptionHandler(org.springframework.validation.BindException.class)
      public ResponseEntity<String> handleBindException(org.springframework.validation.BindException e) {
         return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
      }
   }
```

when `@Valid` fails, it throws BindException. Which you can handle it like this. or you can just do `throw e` which would give you the exact same response as was thrown earlier

Answer (score 2):

One approach is that worked for me is to not extend `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`

So the result class would look like:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
class RestExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(WhateverException.class)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED)
  public ResponseEntity<String> handleWhateverException(WhateverException e, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    System.out.println("Handling a WhateverException.");
    return new ResponseEntity(...);
  }    
}
```

but see also this: [Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282298/ambiguous-exceptionhandler-method-mapped-for-class-org-springframework-web-bin)

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue, after spending lot of time debugging the issue I found the jackson is not properly deserializing the `ErrorResponse` object.

This was because I didn't added the getters and setters for the field defined in the `ErrorResponse` object. I was initializing the fields using constructor and there were no getters and setters defined for those fields.

**SOLUTION (for empty body):**

So when I updated my `ErrorResponse` object from

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRootName;
import java.util.List;

@JsonRootName("error")
public class ErrorResponse {

  private String message;
  private List<String> details;

  public ErrorResponse(String message, List<String> details) {
    this.message = message;
    this.details = details;
  }
}
```

to the following one with getters and setters

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRootName;
import java.util.List;

@JsonRootName("error")
public class ErrorResponse {

  private String message;
  private List<String> details;

  public ErrorResponse(String message, List<String> details) {
    this.message = message;
    this.details = details;
  }

  public String getMessage() {
    return message;
  }

  public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
  }

  public List<String> getDetails() {
    return details;
  }

  public void setDetails(List<String> details) {
    this.details = details;
  }
}
```

Jackson is now deserializing the `ErrorResponse` properly and I'm getting the serialized body in the response.