# I can't write my own @ExceptionHandler for HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, exception, exceptionhandler

I want to return my own error message in rest controller when accept header is "application/xml". The thing is if this header is set then spring throws `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException`. I wanted to use `@ExceptionHandler` and I added a new method in class anotated with `@RestControllerAdvice`, but when I start the application I get error

```
Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException]: {public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity mixss.github_api.exceptionhandlers.HttpResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleMediaTypeNotAcceptableException(org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException), public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest) throws java.lang.Exception
```

which means that there is already `@ExceptionHandler` for this exception, but it is in `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`(not my class)

Of course when I add `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` to `@GetMapping` in controller this exception is not thrown but there is a built-in response I would like to change.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method for HttpMessageNotReadableException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67147660/ambiguous-exceptionhandler-method-for-httpmessagenotreadableexception)

Answer (score 0):

You need to extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler and override the method. Just like reported in: [Getting Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for MethodArgumentNotValidException while startup of spring boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51991992/getting-ambiguous-exceptionhandler-method-mapped-for-methodargumentnotvalidexce)

Comment: I tried to do this but it still doesn't work. I have the class: 
`@RestControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` and method:

```@Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMediaTypeNotAcceptable(HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatusCode status, WebRequest request) {
        throw new WrongMethodTypeException();
    }
```
but it stil not being invoked

Comment: Did you annotate the overrided method with @ExceptionHandler and @ResponseStatus?